# What's the use of LinearLayoutManger in the RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

i want to know that what is the use of LinearLayoutManager class in this code?
i have just made this by seeing a tutorial of android but it doesn't explain it!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView myRecyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);//what's the use?
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(new FriendListAdapter());

    }
}
```

Comment: did you have a look to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LinearLayout means that your child views will be shown in a Linear manner ie one below the other, whereas in case of GridLayoutManager your child views are shown in a form of a grid and same goes for Staggered Grid . I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

make a class extends RecyclerAdapter
and use recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(thisActivity));

```
  recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.activity_main_recyclerView);
    mRecyclerAdapter=new RootRecyclerAdapter(this,new RootRecyclerData().getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(thisActivity));
```